# Inheritance syntax in C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I understand the syntax of inheritance in C++:

```
class DerivedClassName : public BaseClassName {}
```

However, in a program I found a string like that:

```
class ComplexNumberTest : public CppUnit::TestCase {
```

and I do not understand what it means. It is clear that `ComplexNumberTest` is subclass of `CppUnit` but what `TestCase` does their?

I think that `CppUnit::TestCase` means `TestCase` method of `CppUnit` class but then `DerivedClassName` should be a subclass of a method?

Could anybody please help me with that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CppUnit is namespace, ComplexNumberTest is a derived class of TestCase from CppUnit namespace.

In your code, you have TestCase in this way:

```
namespace CppUnit
{
  class TestCase
  {
    // blah blah
  };
}
```

Or it TestCase could be a nested class(type) inside CppUnit with public access(thanks to PeterWood)

```
class CppUnit
{
public:
  class TestCase
  {
    // blah blah
  };
};

class ComplexNumberTest : public CppUnit::TestCase
{
   // also blah
};
```

Comment: It is probably a namespace, but it could by a class declared within another class.

Comment: Or even a `typedef` defined within another class.

Comment: yup, both(nested class or typedef) mean a type inside CppUnit

Comment: no, it's definitely a class in a namespace: http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/lastest/cppunit_cookbook.html

Comment: @thang the link you are referring is good, however a nested class or type also works in this case.

Comment: the reason i posted the link is because it is op's exact piece of code.  that is probably where it's from.  in general, you're right, but in this particular case, it is definitely a class in a namespace.  we know which class and which namespace, too.

Comment: if OP posts a link in original question then it is namespace and I'll answer it that way.

Comment: @thang I knew where the code was from but context is everything when parsing C++. The implementation could change and it would still work.

Answer (score 2):

CppUnit is a namepsace or TestCase is a nested class in CppUnit.

If it is a namespace:
You can get rid of this syntax, by using the namespace:

```
using namespace CppUnit;

class ComplexNumberTest : public TestCase {
```

`Although, you don't usually want to put using namespace in a header file.` - Thank for comment @PeterWood

Comment: Although, you don't usually want to put `using namespace` in a header file.